# Compose an entity object from a 'join' query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this Linq query, that I tried to simplify :

```
  List<A> LR = (from a in ent.A
                              join b in ent.B on a.ID equals b.idarticle
                              join c in ent.C on b.idB equals c.id
                              select new A()
                              { name=a.name, surname = c.surname

    }).toList();
```

in a few words I need a field of A taken from table C (via a cross table B), so that 'name' from A and 'surname' from C compose a new A.

But I get "Cannot build entity type A"... while it's ok for an anonymous type...is it possible to get it ? I know I would need a new class type and populate it, but this is shorter. 
thanks,
Saverio

Answer (score 2):

That error has to do possibly with of restrictions in entity framework. So you could let ef return anonymous object, and then transform it into `List<A>`

```
 List<A> LR = (from a in ent.A
                              join b in ent.B on a.ID equals b.idarticle
                              join c in ent.C on b.idB equals c.id
                              select new 
                              { name=a.name, surname = c.surname

    })toList().Select(anon => new A() { name=anon.name, surname = anon.surname });
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid to go thru anonymous (30 fields to repeat) but at this point I think it's necessary... I'm just afraid of performance, where customer calls you while comparing with sql console... Thanks